# Parallel Merging of two sorted lists

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, data-parallel-haskell

I am trying to merge two list in parallel. I have two sorted lists `[(i, j, val)]`. Lists are sorted on `j` and for same `j`, sorted on `i`. If the two lists contain the same `(i, j)` then their
values are added and combined into one, e.g. if the first list contains `(i, j, val_1)` and the second list contains `(i, j, val_2)` then combining two will result `(i, j, val_1 + val_2)`.

Merging is highly sequential and after searching, I found [this paper](http://alecu.ase.ro/articles/ie_en_2004.pdf). The idea from this paper is to use binary search to get the rank of the elements in the final list. Let's say we are at `i`th position in the first list so we have `(i - 1)` elements smaller than the
current element in first list and perform binary search for this element's position in the second list (say this position is `j`). So the position of our current element in final list will be `i + j - 1` (`i - 1 + j - 1 + 1`). I wrote a Haskell code using dph-par for this but I am kind of stuck with update.  I have two list

```
l_1 = [ (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (4, 1, 1), (1, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1), (4, 4, 1) ]
l_2 = [ (1, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 1), (1, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1), (4, 4, 1) ]
```

and after updating these two lists , we should have

```
l_3 = [ (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (1, 4, 2), (2, 4, 2), (3, 4, 1), (4, 4, 2) ]
```

Bsearch.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelArrays #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fvectorise #-}

module Bsearch ( interfaceSparse ) where
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel as P
import Data.Array.Parallel.PArray
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude as Pre
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude.Int as I
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude.Double as D

bSearch :: ( I.Int , I.Int , D.Double ) -> [: ( I.Int , I.Int ,D.Double ) :] -> I.Int
bSearch elem@( i , j , val ) xs = ret where
  ret = helpBsearch 0 len where
        len = P.lengthP xs
        helpBsearch :: I.Int -> I.Int -> I.Int
        helpBsearch lo hi
           | lo I.>= hi = lo
           | cond  = helpBsearch ( mid I.+ 1 ) hi
           | otherwise = helpBsearch lo mid
           where mid = I.div ( lo I.+ hi ) 2
             ( i' , j' , val' ) = xs P.!: mid
             cond = case () of
                     _| j' I.< j Pre.|| ( j I.== j' Pre.&& i' I.<i )  -> True
                      | otherwise ->  False

bSearchFun :: [: ( I.Int , I.Int , D.Double ) :] -> [: ( I.Int ,I.Int , D.Double ) :] -> [:I.Int :]
bSearchFun xs ys = P.mapP ( \( x , y ) -> x I.+ y ) ( P.indexedP ( P.mapP  ( \x ->  bSearch x ys ) xs ) )

bSearchMain :: [: ( I.Int , I.Int , D.Double ) :] -> [: ( I.Int , I.Int , D.Double ) :] -> [: ( I.Int  , ( I.Int , I.Int , D.Double ) ) :]
bSearchMain xs ys = l_1 where --here change l_2 for second list
    lst = [: bSearchFun xs ys  , bSearchFun ys xs  :]
    first = lst P.!: 0
    second = lst P.!: 1
    l_1 = P.zipP first xs
    l_2 = P.zipP second ys

interfaceSparse :: PArray ( Int , Int , Double )  ->  PArray ( Int ,Int , Double )  -> PArray   ( Int , ( Int , Int , Double ) )
{-# NOINLINE interfaceSparse #-}
interfaceSparse  xs ys = P.toPArrayP ( bSearchMain ( P.fromPArrayPxs ) ( P.fromPArrayP ys ) )
```

Main.hs

```
module Main where
import Bsearch
import qualified Data.Array.Parallel.PArray as P
import Data.List

main = do
 let
   l_1 = P.fromList $ ( [ ( 1 , 1 , 1 ) , ( 2 , 1 , 1)  , ( 4 , 1 , 1 ) , ( 1 , 4 , 1 ) ,( 2 , 4 , 1 ) , ( 4 ,4 , 1 ) ] :: [ ( Int ,Int , Double ) ] )
   l_2 = P.fromList $ ( [ ( 1 , 1 , 1 ) , ( 3 , 1 , 1 ) , ( 4 , 1 , 1) , ( 1 , 4 , 1 ) , ( 3 , 4 , 1 ) , ( 4 , 4 , 1 ) ] :: [ ( Int , Int , Double )] )
   e = interfaceSparse l_1 l_2
 print e
```

```
[ntro@localhost parBsearch]$ ghc -c -Odph -fdph-par -fforce-recomp Bsearch.hs
[ntro@localhost parBsearch]$ ghc -c -Odph -fdph-par -fforce-recomp Main.hs
[ntro@localhost parBsearch]$ ghc -o Bsearch -threaded -rtsopts -fdph-par Main.o Bsearch.o

[ntro@localhost parBsearch]$ ./Bsearch --first list
fromList<PArray> [(0,(1,1,1.0)),(2,(2,1,1.0)),(4,(4,1,1.0)),(6,(1,4,1.0)),(8,(2,4,1.0)),(10 (4,4,1.0))]
[ntro@localhost parBsearch]$ ./Bsearch  -- second list
fromList<PArray> [(0,(1,1,1.0)),(3,(3,1,1.0)),(4,(4,1,1.0)),(6,(1,4,1.0)),(9,(3,4,1.0)),(10,(4,4,1.0))]
```

Could some one please help me with update. I am not sure but this algorithm involves lot of data movement so kindly suggest me something better for this purpose.

Comment: I don't understand how multiple collisions are handled.  If you merge a list with itself, you should get a new list with the same keys, but all the values doubled.  If each element is put-in-place in parallel, how does the process that is dealing with element X[i] know that there was a collision for all elements with index j < i, and not just the current index?  Maybe the algorithm leaves holes in the result?

Comment: @pat If I got you correctly then yes it leaves hole in my case ( merging the element containing same i , j ). If we consider the example from post , there will be ( 0 , 0 , 0 ) at position 1 but we can filter it using filterP.

Comment: @hammer thanks for formatting the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the haskell language, but when I merge sorted lists, I use bitonic sort. This is a great algorithm, and highly parallel in design. The only restriction is that you merge lists of size 2^n. I get around this restriction by padding the short lists with values higher than the known values in the lists, so they accumulate together and can be ignored. I have such huge lists to sort that the power of 2 limitation is easy to accommodate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd-even_mergesort